# title of a custom button

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am creating a custom UIButton like this :

U

```
IButton *buttonDetailCarte = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonDetailCarte.frame = CGRectMake(8, 223, 304, 44);
        [buttonDetailCarte setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellule.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonDetailCarte.titleLabel.text = @" my Text";
        buttonDetailCarte.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17];
        buttonDetailCarte.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:84.0/255 green:84.0/255 blue:84.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
        buttonDetailCarte.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        buttonDetailCarte.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

the problem that my Text don't appear in my button and when i create the same button with IB, it appear ? what's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`setTitle:forControlState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) method to change the button text, not manipulate the button's titleLabel directly.

Manipulating other properties of the `titleLabel`, as you are doing, is also no recommended. Try using the `setTitleColor:` instead. However, other properties like `font` of the titleLabel are fine to change. It's confusing at first but you get used to it!